# Is there scala compiler option that makes ` Option[T](t).map(x => null)` return None instead of Some(null)

Tags: scala, scalac, scala-compiler

I've enterprise polyglot codebase which is made of java and scala.

We have lot of places where we do map function on `Option[T]` and the mapping function is legacy code which returns null.

`Option(2).map(x => null)` returns `Some(null)`. when another higher order function is applied on the result it throws NullPointerException.

As a workaround we do `Option[T](t).map(x => Option(mapping(x)))` in order to make this result `None`. It is slowly becoming code smell.

I'm trying to see whether there is any better way to do this or there is scala compiler option that return `None` when the calls like this  `Option[T](t).map(x => null)` are made automagically.

Comment: No there isn't, because **Scala's** `Option` is a proper **Monad** not like **Java's** `Optional` - `Some(null)` is a perfectly valid value, just one you would never see in idiomatic code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I don't think there is much wrong with your workaround given you have to work with legacy APIs that return null but you have to flatMap it like so

```
Option(t).flatMap(x => Option(legacyJavaFunc(x)))
```

You could invest in a Scala wrapper layer which handles dealing with nulls and exceptions behind the scenes so then you don't have to call Java API directly

```
// Scala API layer over Java API
def scalaFunc[T](t: T): Option[T] = Option(legacyJavaFunc(t))

// so we can avoid calling Java API directly
Option(t).flatMap(scalaFunc)
```

Execution of `legacyJavaFunc` happens at run-time so compiler cannot predict the result in advance at compile-time to rewrite it automagically.